# az cli - list virtual machines with specific extensions installed on

Tags: azure-cli

From the json produced with `"az vm list -o json"` I need to find names of VMs which are having any of below two extensions installed:

AADSSH**LoginForLinux**

AAD**LoginForLinux**

What would be the *--query* that would list VMs having "LoginForLinux" in the extension name?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `| grep` ?
Something like that :
`az vm list -o json | grep -F 'LoginForLinux'` :
This would output the lines where there is "LoginForLinux" pattern, but could be chained with other | and grep to have a more accurate result.